# Intl.defaultLocale is set, only dates change their format but not the numbers

Tags: flutter, dart

As soon as I change my app language from **Arabic **to **English **and vice versa, the format of all dates displays correctly according the language set. Only numbers representing amounts, quantities, etc. still displayed in English format (1, 2, 3...). All what I do is `Intl.defaultLocale = languageProvider.locale.toString();` in the main.

After searching, I found that's better to write my own method to display numbers according the language set and here is my code

```
static String get _nfLocale =>
      appLanguage == LanguageEnum.ar.name ? 'ar_EG' : 'en_US';

static NumberFormat get nf => NumberFormat.decimalPattern(_nfLocale);

String formatN(
  double n, {
  bool keepCommaSeparator = false,
  String newSeparator = ' ',
}) {
  final f = nf;
  return f.format(n);
}
```

Now, to have numbers displayed well when Arabic language is set, I have to call **formatN** everywhere I have them !

Is it the correct way to do that ? is there any solution to set it once as the system does for dates ?